# Log onto github using the same github account on different users from the same machine

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

Is there a way to use the Github for Windows client from two different users on the same computer, using the same Github account?

Basically I have two users that I log in on, on the same machine. One is for everyday use and the other for testing. If I set up my credentials on one of the users, and then switch over to the other user and set up Gtihub for Windows on that user, it overwrites my ssh key for that computer since it looks like when the Github client logs you on, it sets up the ssh key by computer, not by computer and user.

Any ideas on how to share the generated ssh key between the two user accounts on the same machine?

**Update:**

On Greg's suggestion, I copied the ssh keys (contents of `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh`) from one user to the other. I then started the ssh agent:

```
ssh-agent -s
```

and then added the key:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/github_rsa
```

If I then run:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

I get back:

```
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,XXX.XX.XXX.XXX' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Hi MYUSERNAME! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

But then if I try to go into one of my repos and run `git fetch origin`, I get prompted for my username and login.

Comment: Why not just copy the SSH key from one user to another?

Comment: I copied the two files from `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh` from one user to the other and that doesn't seem sufficient to make github recognize my user

Comment: After copying the SSH key, did you restart any open Git Bash shells? Maybe reboot, because I'm sure an SSH client is running in the background in Windows, and lord knows you can't touch anything in Windows without rebooting.

Comment: Don't forget to add the SSH key to the ssh-agent

Comment: I added more details about the steps I followed in the **Update**

Comment: What url have you used to clone the project (`git remote -v`)?

Comment: @joran the urls as the https ones, but they match the urls in the repo in the other account that are working with the credentials setup by Github for Windows Desktop.